# htaccess add some more redirects and also hide extentions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

hello all i am having this htaccess file to my public_html folder and i want some more redirects

the code that htaccess has

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ http://www.domain.com [L]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
       ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
       ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
      Options -Indexes 

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page1\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page1.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the page redirects all the page1.php?url=abc to domain/abc
but now i need to redirect all the requests to page2.php?id=78 to domain/page2/78

and if possible also hide all the .php extentions from my site i have no idea about htaccess .. please help me understand the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ http://www.domain.com [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(page2)\.php\?id=(\d+)[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(page2)/(\d+)$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page1\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page1.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: sir, do i have to remove the extentions form my page links also like i have to change anchor links href='pahe.php' to href='page' ???

Comment: ok sir, actually the code is excelent and it works great but the only problem is that some form submition is not working after i update my htaccess file .. i just wanted to know do i  have to change anything more after updating my htaccess file .. all forms are submitted by ajax and there is a url i think it might be a issue ??

Comment: but the page page2.php?id=43 redirects to page2?id=43 i want page2/id/43 can you do this ??